# Running a command from a string with parameters in go

Tags: go

I am trying to run a command with go. The command is in a string.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"

    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
)

func main() {
    commandToRun := `echo $HOME`

    log.Printf("Running %s\n", commandToRun)

    args := strings.Fields(commandToRun)
    spew.Dump(args[1:len(args)])
    command := exec.Command(args[0], args[1:len(args)]...)
    command.Stdout = os.Stdout
    command.Stdin = os.Stdin
    command.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := command.Run()

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
2018/11/14 09:41:22 Running echo $HOME
([]string) (len=1 cap=1) {
 (string) (len=5) "$HOME"
}
$HOME
```

What I'd like to have is:

```
2018/11/14 09:41:22 Running echo $HOME
([]string) (len=1 cap=1) {
 (string) (len=5) "$HOME"
}
/home/whatever
```

Looks like go is sanitizing the string somehow. So the `$HOME` is not expanded. Is there any way of running the string exactly as if it was typed into the shell?

This is the important part. Ideally I'd like to turn from string to type in the current shell.

EDIT: The example below solve the simplest scenario but doesn't cover the "running the string exactly as if it was typed into the shell" part.

If I switch to `expandenv`:

```
commandToRun := os.ExpandEnv(`echo "$HOME"`)
```

I get:

```
2018/11/14 11:45:44 Running echo "/Users/rafael"
([]string) (len=1 cap=1) {
 (string) (len=15) "\"/home/whatever\""
}
"/home/whatever"
```

What I'd get in the shell is:

```
$ > echo "$HOME"
/home/whatever
```

without the quotes.

This is close to what I want but not exactly it.

Comment: `Looks like go is sanitizing the string somehow so the $HOME is not expanded.` No, its not expanded because nobody expanded them. The shell does expansion, you're not invoking a shell, you're calling the command directly.

Comment: Ok, true, makes sense. But then I guess I cannot run the command in the current executing shell unless I save it to a script file or some dirty trick like that.

Comment: Is [os.Getenv()](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv) of use to you?

Comment: BTW, `exec.Command(args[0], args[1:len(args)]...)` can be shortened to: `exec.Command(args...)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exec.Command() in Go with environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015569/exec-command-in-go-with-environment-variable)

Comment: It is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015569/exec-command-in-go-with-environment-variable

Comment: Added an edit since the solution below only solves my particular example and doesn't cover all cases. I tried to clarify a bit. Thanks for all the answers anyway.

Comment: And even if you couldn't do `exec.Command(args...)`, the `len` part is not needed.  If `a` is a slice or array, then the statement `a[n:len(a)]` is identical to the statement `a[n:]`, just as `a[0:n]` is identical to `a[:n]` (and `a[:]` is equivalent to `a[0:len(a)]`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before executing the command, you can actively expand all env vars in the string using `os.ExpandEnv`:

```
os.ExpandEnv("echo $HOME")
```

From the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#ExpandEnv):

> ExpandEnv replaces ${var} or $var in the string according to the values of the current environment variables. References to undefined variables are replaced by the empty string.

Answer (score 5):

`$HOME` (and all other env variables) are expanded by the shell. You're not executing a shell, so they don't get expanded.

You need to look up the env variable directly in go, with something like:

```
command := exec.Command("echo", os.Getenv("HOME"))
```

or this:

```
commandToRun := os.ExpandEnv("echo $HOME")
args := strings.Fields(commandToRun)
command := exec.Command(args[0], args[1:]...)
```

Note that this last approach won't work if `$HOME` expands to a string containing whitespace, so the `os.Getenv` method is generally safer/preferred for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the output of `$ echo $HOME`, the minimal code you need is

```
fmt.Println(os.Getenv("HOME"))
```

Nothing more is needed.

- If you use `os.ExpandEnv("echo $HOME")`, then first `$HOME` var will be expanded and then it will give you a string like `echo /home/<user>`
- If you use `command := exec.Command("echo", os.Getenv("HOME"))`, then it will be resolved as `command := exec.Command("echo", "/home/<user>")` and finally which will give output `/home/<user>`
- If you use

  `commandToRun := os.ExpandEnv("echo $HOME")
  command := exec.Command(strings.Fields(commandToRun)...)`

  then it will be process like previous cases.

So better way is using only `fmt.Println(os.Getenv("HOME"))`.

Comment: I would assume that `echo $HOME` is just an example, not the actual behavior the OP is aiming for.

Comment: If so, then the OP already know how to use `exec.Command()`. But he asked for help because in that way it is not giving the expected result. That's why I answered this way. Isn't it helpful?

Comment: I interpret the question broadly as "How do expand environment variables when execing a command".

Comment: You see, in that case my answer isn't appropriate.

Comment: Then it is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015569/exec-command-in-go-with-environment-variable

Comment: Yes, which is why I have already voted to close as a duplicate :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a shell.  Expanding this in Go seems silly and error prone since you have a shell that you can run.

```
commandToRun := `echo "$SHELL"`
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", commandToRun)
command := exec.Command(args[0], args[1:len(args)]...)
command.Stdout = os.Stdout
command.Stdin = os.Stdin
command.Stderr = os.Stderr
err := command.Run()
```

This should work on any POSIX system.  Kids today put a lot of bashisms in their command lines so you could switch it to run `/bin/bash` but just be aware that won't work on FreeBSD or some other systems (other BSDs and their derivatives at a start).

Comment: Nice. This actually answers the question.